# Creating a bar chart with MPAndroidChart using double values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

Hi I am trying to create a bar chart using MPAndroidChart library in Android Studio for my java application. I have managed to plot a bar chart using single integer values, but I would like to plot double values.

Here is my code for plotting single integer values

```
public class walk extends AppCompatActivity {

HorizontalBarChart barChart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_walk);

    barChart = (HorizontalBarChart) findViewById(R.id.bargraph);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(10f,0));
    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(5f,1));
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"ACTIVITIES");

    ArrayList <String> pa = new ArrayList<>();
    pa.add("WALKING");
    pa.add("RUNNING");

    BarData theData = new BarData(pa,barDataSet);
    barChart.setData(theData);
    barDataSet.setBarSpacePercent(70f);

}
```

I would like to plot the following values 20.333333333333332 and 2.0071271275749623.

I would appreciate any help I could get, apologies if anything is unclear I am new to this site.

Comment: looks like the library supports only float values. You can convert your double values to float before adding to bar entry.

Comment: @BadhrinathCanessane Hi thank you for your help, it much appreciated. It's worked!

Comment: Just added an answer which might help other users with same issue. Still not a great workaround, the library should ideally support doubles. This issue is flagged as an enhancement in their repo.

Comment: Same issues here when applied this value to bar (1000000000) app crashes .Is there any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Converting double to float before plotting :

```
    double point1 = 20.333333333333332;
    double point2 = 2.0071271275749623;
    float fp1 = (float)point1;
    float fp2 = (float)point2;
    ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
       barEntries.add(new BarEntry(fp1,0));
       barEntries.add(new BarEntry(fp2,1));
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"ACTIVITIES");
```